# How to reduce the size of a MySQL table that is over 20GB although it is empty?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table with a size over 20 GB but with no rows in it!!??!!. How can i reduce the size of the table so its not taking so much space?I have tried optimize button on phpmyadmin >> structure

[image]

Comment: *but with no rows in it* Where this fact is taken from? screenshot claims that the table is full of data... If this table is really empty then create its duplicate (`CREATE TABLE new_table AS old_table`), drop old table and rename new one. Do not forget to save/recreate FKs and triggers.

Comment: It is a jobs processing table that was full of data ( 25 rows * 72 pages ) i have emptied the table but it is still showing 28 G.I will Try that, but I am trying to find a way to prevent this from happening again

Comment: *i have emptied the table* How do you do this? Why you're sure that emptying is successful?

Comment: I did a truncate from inside phpmyadmin and check it from ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`, then:

Study the `innodb_file_per_table` Variable.

If it was `OFF` when the table was created, the table is located in the file `ibdata1`, which grows but never shrinks.  The only cure is several rather drastic steps.  But it is not necessarily "bad"; `INSERTs` into table will fill in that free space.

If it was `ON` when the table was created, then the data (zero rows) and the indexes (also empty) are sitting in a 20GB file whose name ends in `.ibd`.  Simply do `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;` or, equivalently, `OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;`

Will this task be repeated?  If so, let's discuss how to do "big deletes", or use of Partitioning if you have a time series, or how to replace all the data by creating a new table, then using `RENAME`.

**If MyISAM**

- You should change to InnoDB.
- Simply do `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename;` to free up the space.

Comment: The engine is MyISAM

Comment: @Nada - I added to my Answer.

Comment: A good reason to pick `ALTER TABLE... ENGINE=InnoDB` as the preferred solution.